# JS: Event not showing in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for the first time. I've copied the supplied script tags into my page's header.

I can visit the page and I see one visitor in real time reports. In addition to recording the number of visitors to the page, I also want to report an event when a user clicks on a particular button on the page.

I have some jQuery to handle the click:

```
$("#new-preview").click(function(){
  new_preview()
  ga('send', 'event', 'preview', 'new', 'v1');
  console.log('Click!')
})
```

I can see that the function runs because the expected text is logged to the console. However, no events are recorded in Google Analytics (Reports -> Real-Time -> Events). I following the instructions provided by Google here. I *think* I'm following them correctly.

Why isn't the event being recorded? What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ga(...)` calls works with ~old~ analytics.js snippet. You're probably using the new gtag.js snippet. In that case you'll need another call to track events, something like

```
gtag('event', 'new', {
  'event_category': 'preview',
  'event_label': 'v11'
});
```

Check the docs for analytics.js [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)
and for gtag.js [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data)